# django rest auth - FacebookLogin view, missing 1 required positional argument 'request'

Tags: django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm following the django-rest-auth Social Authentication installation guide for Facebook, and have implemented the FacebookLogin class as a subclass of SocialLoginView, with adapter_class set to the FacebookOAuth2Adapter adapter, as per the install guide.

When I then post a request to /rest-auth/facebook I get the following error message "TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request' " from registration_serializers.py, line 63 (adapter = adapter_class() )

Am I missing a setting? Perhaps an allauth social setting somewhere? Thanks

Comment: i'm getting the same thing after recently updating django/allauth/rest_auth. Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug with django-rest-auth and django-allauth > 0.25.

Workaround is to pass an init into the adapter, I've verified this works with my project.

```
class FacebookOAuth2AdapterCustom(FacebookOAuth2Adapter):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class FacebookLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = FacebookOAuth2AdapterCustom
```

An issue with django-rest-auth has been submitted: https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/197